# audio in my phaser.js game is not playing on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, audio, phaser-framework

I have the following code in `preload`:

```
this.load.audio('theme', './audio/theme.mp3');
```

and in `create()`:

```
gameState.music = this.sound.add('theme');
gameState.music.play();
gameState.music.loop = true;
```

I also added in `config` following some info i found out there:

```
audio: {
    disableWebAudio: true
}
```

It works on desktop and iphone, but not on android. Funny thing that it worked before i made some - unrelated to audio - changes to the game.

Comment: I'm just asking to be on the save side, is `play` being called before any user input? like in the create function? Sound won't play if there is no user input.

Comment: it is. so i changed it to `this.input.on('pointerup', () => {
            gameState.music.play();
            this.scene.stop('FirstScene');
            this.scene.start('Level1');
              
        });` . Same, works on desktop, i assume it would continue to work on iphone, but doesn't work on my android.

Comment: The current verison on Github  https://github.com/chylinski82/androidCoop, works fine on Android, have you updated it.

Comment: must be a newer android then, cause on my galaxy s9 (not 9 plus) and on my kids old galaxy tablet it's not working, even if I put it inside an on event function. Another issue that i didn't have a chance to post yet is that on iOS devices, it doesn't want to go automatically into full screen mode.

Comment: btw.: you could post your question/problem also on https://phaser.discourse.group/ many phaser pro's are answering questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and some testing here some more infos, on how to get the Audio, work *consistently*, on iphone or Android:

1. It seems that for Mobile (iOs or Android) you might need to `unlock` the audio/sound.

in the `SoundScene` just adapt the `create` function, to mirror these changes:

```
 create() {
    this.input.once('pointerdown', _ => {
        // UNLOCK audio, doesn't work immediately on iphone
        this.sound.unlock();
        gameState.music = this.sound.add('theme2', {loop: true});
        
        // if unlock worked, just play the sound
        if(!this.sound.locked){
            gameState.music.play();
        } 
        else {  // IF Not wait on unlock event 
            this.sound.once(Phaser.Sound.Events.UNLOCKED, () => {
                gameState.music.play();
            })
        }
    });
}
```

2. With the current config / code, this should work with Android, but not with iPhone.
3. If you remove the `disableWebAudio:true` from the `config` configutation in the `game.js` - file, than it works on iPhone, but not on Android. *Strange*

Currently this are the only two configurations, how I could get the audio to work on android and iPhone. I couldn't find a single configuration, that works for both.

**Update:** I retested everything, it seems to work, with the `SoundScene` changes, on win 10, android and iphone, with `disableWebAudio:true` using a `mp3`- file.

Comment: thanks again for your help, as adviced  i tried with `mp3`, both files, `theme` - +4MB and `theme2` - 1.1MB. It didn't work , though once randomly worked on my kids Samsung galaxy tabA (with `theme2`). Then i tried updating system software on all my devices, bot tablets TabA and my Galaxy S9, after that it works on tablets (only `theme2` though), still doesn't work on my Galaxy S9. Because i tried updating my devices only now, i can't tell for sure if it works on tablets only because of the system update or also because the changes that you introduced, nevertheless i kept these changes.

Comment: **update** i did post the question on phaser forum and someone came back saying that `sound.unlock` was a solution that he was looking for for his own projects, so more credit for you. Also he said, he tested my game and it worked on android devices even with a 13MB `.mp3` file, so I'm just gonna assume I'm fking something up with my devices and that the solution is the final one, can't make it any better and just call it a day.

Answer (score 2):

There are some points to unpack, so I opted, for a *anwser* instead of a *comment*.
*(Sorry that it is so long, I tried to keep it short)*

1. You change the Audio file type from `mp3` (which is well supported over many devices, especially older), to `ogg` which is not as well supported _(tipp: [best info page for information to browser feature support](https://caniuse.com/?search=ogg))

   - specific android version support say's android 5.0+ should be able to play `ogg` file ([android version table](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#audio-formats)), I tested it on Android 5.5, it works. So if the andorid version is not under 5.0, and you tap the screen only once, and no sound is playing, there is a different issue.
   - iphone should not work (`ogg` is not supported, if I can belief the apple forum posts), **but** I tested it on iPhone SE 2015 and it works. *Strange*

     - <strike>*btw.: fullscreen also works, but only on the safari browser, not chrome*</strike> I tap scrolled
2. Mobile devices need user interaction to play sounds/music, so if you let the page load and don't tap the screen, the music shouldn't (won't) play. After tap the music starts. This is the part, where we are entering *uncharted* territory:

   - You are starting the music in the Scene 'FirstScene', but this Scene is stopped after first tap. Theoretically everything in the Scene will/should be unloaded, but the music plays on. *(This fact seems to be know, but is still Strange, to me)*

***Personally I would:***

- call the `play()` function only after a user interaction, this prevents possible problems due to the "browser blocking",
- use `mp3` since it wider supported,
- [and optional] if possible keep the sounds / music it the same Scene, and if the scene is closed/stopped, I would stop any audio, that was initiated in that Scene. Or even handle all the sound in a seperate always running scene like mentioned, in this [forum post](https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/38921-sounds-keep-looping-after-changing-scene/?do=findComment&comment=222881). *(But I usually always have a "always-running"-scene which manages my scene switches and other background actions)*

**But**, it seems okay, since currently it works on my local server, for:

- Win10 Chrome 104+
- iPhone SE 2015 safari, *fullscreen won't work on iphone, if we can [trust this site](https://caniuse.com/fullscreen)*
- Android 5.5 Chrome
- Android 11.0 Chrome

**Update Sound Manager Option:**

an "easy" way is to add 2 extra Scenes

**BootScene**:

```
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super({ key: 'BootScene' })
    }

    create() {
        // `launch` starts a scene without stopping other
        this.scene.launch('FirstScene');
        this.scene.launch('SoundScene');
    }
}
```

**SoundScene:**
*Scene that runs parallel to the game*

```
class SoundScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super({ key: 'SoundScene' })
    }

    preload(){
        this.load.audio('theme', './audio/theme.ogg');
    }

    create() {
        this.input.once('pointerdown', _ => {
            gameState.music = this.sound.add('theme');
            gameState.music.play();
            gameState.music.loop = true; 
        });
    }

}
```

And make some minor tweaks:

**index.html**
*(add new Scenes)*

```
...
  <script src="BootScene.js"></script>
  <script src="SoundScene.js"></script>
...
```

**game.js**
*(add new Scenes to `config`)*

```
...
config = {
    ...
    scene: [BootScene, SoundScene, FirstScene, ...],
    ...
}
...
```

**FirstScene.js:**

- Remove the **theme** stuff from `preload` and the `create` function.
- add extra checks to prevent errors *(check if `gameState.music` is set already)*

```js
update() {
     if (gameState.music && !document.hasFocus()) {
         gameState.music.pause(); 
    }
    if (gameState.music && document.hasFocus()) {
        gameState.music.resume();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much for looking into it. It's good news that you find it (music) working on all devices, unfortunately i can't say the same. although it worked randomly on my phone once, tonight and after i reloaded the page it stopped again. i tried moving the music to scene level 1 and leaving in initial scene but after using interaction, but to no avail. I'm glad that full screen worked on your iphone, but it doesn't work on my wife's and didn't work on my colleage's either, which makes it impossible to play properly. I'm trying different things, so far seems like a dead end.

Comment: sorry, i just noticed the link to the post about separate scene (audio manager). maybe that could work, but i don't know from the top of my head how to run it (would it be before FirstScene or simultaneously and if simultaneously then how to do it(???)). I need to look around and see how do i go about that...

Comment: @chylinski sorry, I updated my answer _(several this, usually I mark the updated parts better)_ the fullscreen doesn't work on Iphone it might on iPad. This feature is not supported.

Comment: @chylinski just added another update, with an short example how I set up my "background" Scenes. **p.s.:** the sound might not be playing because the sound file seems abit big, you could try a smaller one < 1MB just to see if the size or the load time could be an issue

Comment: @chylinski btw. the code is not using the newest Version of phaser. The `index.html` links to the version 3.16.2, but the version 3.55.2 is currently the "current stable version".

Comment: thanks for the update, it looks great! though it didn't help with the sound i'm keeping it because of how neat it looks and for future reference. I also tried playing a smaller music file (1.1MB) and i've updated the phaser version, still  no music on android. The strangest thing is that it used to work fine before. That was before i made unrelated changes to the game, mainly when i used to have static images as character, instead of the current animation.

Comment: @chylinski it is a strange, but interesting problem. did you try using mp3 again? I know ogg should work, but just to be on the save side.

Comment: i actually did it in mp3 right away. because you're asking now i tried .ogg, same.